# Disable SSL in PHP 5.6 getimagesize()

Tags: php, ssl, php-5.6

Below php code works perfectly fine with php5.4 but as soon as i move to 5.6 below code crashes.

```
$url = "urlofanimage";
$out = getimagesize($url);
print_r($out);
```

We are getting
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in ...

**Solution:**
I know there is a way to disable SSL verification when using get_put_contents() but can we solved it

1> Global php.ini settings

2> changing code to minimum

Comment: Don't just ignore SSL errors. If you do, you introduce a potential attack vector.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol as a urgent need i need to disable ?

Comment: No. Because I guarantee that you won't come back and do it properly later.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol do u have a solution for temp disabling ?

Comment: I don't. But if you find one, be sure to do something like `if( date("Ymd") < "20180620") { /* bypass thing here */ } else throw new Exception("FIX THIS THING!");`

Comment: Why moving to 5.6 now? It is obsolete in 6 months. If you change versions, go at least to 7.1. And **NO** disabling TLS checks is **NOT** the way to go forward. Investigate what is wrong with this certificate (see further parts of the error message) and have a read at https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf for some good practices.

Comment: still...any solution availble in 5.6 ?

Comment: Also can i get SSL verification  for free ?